# Redux useSelector hook doesn't retrieve updated state

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, react-hooks

Working on making private routes and need to redirect if the user is not authenticated, but `useSelector()` is not getting updated state. I have also provided a screenshot of my state using `redux-devtools`

**App.js**

```
  const App = () => {
   const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(loadUser());
  }, []);

  return (
    <Router>
      <Switch>
        <Route path='/' exact component={Home} />
        <Route path='/register' exact component={Register} />
        <Route path='/login' exact component={Login} />
        <PrivateRoute component={Dashboard} path='/dashboard' exact />
      </Switch>
    </Router>
  );
};
```

**load User Action**

```
const loadSuccess = (data) => {
  return {
    type: AUTH_SUCCESS,
    payload: data,
  };
};

const loadFailure = (errors) => {
  return {
    type: AUTH_FAILURE,
    payload: errors,
  };
};

export const loadUser = () => {
  return async (dispatch) => {
    try {
      const res = await axios.get('/users/current');
      dispatch(loadSuccess(res.data));
    } catch (error) {
      dispatch(loadFailure(error));
    }
  };
};
```

--edited: **authReducer.js**

```
const initialState = {
  token: null,
  isAuth: false,
  loading: true,
  user: null,
  errors: [],
};

const authReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case AUTH_SUCCESS:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: localStorage.getItem('token'),
        isAuth: true,
        loading: false,
        user: action.payload,
        errors: [],
      };
    case AUTH_FAILURE:
      return {
        ...state,
        token: localStorage.removeItem('token'),
        isAuth: false,
        loading: true,
        user: null,
        errors: action.payload,
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default authReducer;
```

**PrivateRoute.js**

```
const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, ...rest }) => {
  const isAuth = useSelector((state) => state.authReducer.isAuth);
  console.log(isAuth);
  return (
    <Route
      {...rest}
      render={(props) =>
        isAuth ? <Component {...props} /> : <Redirect exact to='/' />
      }
    />
  );
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

So far I believe the action is dispatching properly in the main `App.js` file, and the state is getting updated as shown in image below:

[image]

But `console.log(isAuth);` shows `false`.
Any Idea what's wrong here?

Comment: Can you show your reducer code?

Comment: @BrianThompson I added the reducer code.

Comment: I don't see anything obviously wrong. Are you going to a protected route directly after login so before AUTH_SUCCESS has dispatched?

Comment: @HMR for that im taking care of it my `login.js` file and it works fine. here what I can't figure is why `isAuth` is still  `false` even though im seeing it changes in devTool